# How to know which UIView index or tag has been shown by UIScrollView?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uiscrollview

I have an `UIScrollView` with lots of tagged images.
I have to process some code after the user selects a specific image inside the `UIScrollView`. To do this process I need to know which image or view `UIScrollView` was showing when the user selected it.

I tried tracking the `frame.origin.x` of my subviews, but without success.

Can you guys share something about this situation?

Comment: How are you displaying the images inside the scroll view? Are they UIImageViews or are you drawing them some other way?

Comment: Yes, the images are inside UIImageViews. Inside a "for" I have: [scrollImage addSubview:imageView];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin of the scrollview's `bounds` determine the visible area.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai. With this information I'm able to solve my problem.